# Not able to identify xpath through Accessibility inspector in IOS app

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

[image: Xcode hierarchy inspection]

Label/value is not defined here for the password input box I'm so not able to identify how to set the xpath

Comment: image is attached-https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6HMF.png

Answer (score 0):

The inspector in [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) should be able to provide you the Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with iOS Inspects but with my website it gives me 1)Copy Selector , 2)Copy Xpath options for particular element which you want to select

steps for it:

1)Inspect
2)right click on element which you want to select or locate
3)click copy which will provide you options for locators as Copy Selector and Xpath

I hope it may help you